# Vue.js: inline styles can't overwrite other styles

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

My code looks like this:

```
<div
    class="title"
    :style="{
    fontSize: (object.text.length > 8 ? '0.7' : '1') + 'em'
}">
    {{object.text}}
</div>
```

As you can see in this screenshot, this code doesn't overwrite other styles:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7uGZ.png

If I use "!important" flag, it doesn't add any styles at all

```
<div
  class="title"
  :style="{
    fontSize: (object.text.length > 8 ? '0.7' : '1') + 'em !important'
}">
  {{object.text}}
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you just overwrite .title and unset font-size !important?

Comment: I can't do this for a couple of reasons, but I changed the name of class and it works now

Comment: Good. Post your answer and how you did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class "title" was from other framework, so I just changed the name of this class and it works fine now